# Bluetooth communication between Mac and iPhone

Tags: iphone, macos, keyboard, bluetooth, hid

I want to write an app communicating between Mac and iPhone.

Specifically speaking, I want to write a mac app which translates the input from mac and sends it to mac.
For example, if I type 'a' on mac, the app changes it into 'ah' on iPhone.
Another example, if I type 'a' on mac, the app changes it into 'あ' in Japanese on iPhone.

To write this kind of app, What documentation should I refer?

Please let me know, what documentation should I read.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this, 
The iPhone supports standard bluetooth profiles and a general purpose app like what you have mentioned will require the mac to act like an iPhone Bluetooth accessory (which requires it be be as per [Apple MFi requirements](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/))

You can do it by connecting an external compatible Bluetooth hardware to the Mac which can make it act like an accessory then write your app for the required function.